# Microphone not working on ubuntu 18.04 with device Multichannel input-sof-hda-dsp

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

Headphone works properly but microphone is not working on my ubuntu 18.04. The input level bar doesn't change which indicates the microphone doesn't detect any sound.

`Pulseeffect` is installed on my laptop and i am not sure if the problem started after installing it. so uninstalled and restarted my pc but still sound input not working. Some help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was having the same problem on ubuntu 18.04 LTS, running this command will get your mic working, but the volume might be a little low

```
pacmd load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,6
```

to increase the volumen, you may need to run `alsamixer` in the terminal and jack up everything with PGA in the name, but I believe the mic will work after that. Ubuntu has stumbled a bit on the support for this new audio driver

Comment: yeah works but decreases output volume significantly

Comment: To help others who are like me - to jack up mic volume go to Capture by clicking F4 while being inside alsamixer. Then increase the capture volume with PGA like the answer suggested. Works perfectly after this [@mahfujasif hopefully this helps you]. Also, you can add above command to 'Start Up Applications' to avoid having to run the command every time you switch on Ubuntu. Otherwise, it got reset after I shut down the computer.

Comment: I get an error : "Module load failed." Any solution to this?