# Mic not working after installing Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on my new Lenovo ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-8

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, microphone, soundcard

I bought a new Lenovo ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-8.
My mic is not working at all.

I have Multichannel sof-hda-dsp under my input tab in "Sounds". Mic is on, but seems like doesn't work.

Any idea what can be done? The few solutions in the forums did not help.

Thanks

Comment: This issue is discussed here: [18.04 issues with X1 Carbon: alsamixer config + Microphone issues: What does “pacmd” do here?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336087/18-04-issues-with-x1-carbon-alsamixer-config-microphone-issues-what-does-pa)

Comment: @Raffa and that works!

Answer (score 2):

This specific model has a multichannel input that is relatively new and although supported by Ubuntu 18.04, the device must be manually identified using PulseAudio's `module-alsa-source` like so:

```
pacmd load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,6
```

- Please, note that you need to run `alsamixer` afterwords and unmute the newly added input device.
- The above solution is discussed in detail in this post: [18.04 issues with X1 Carbon: alsamixer config + Microphone issues: What does “pacmd” do here?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336087/18-04-issues-with-x1-carbon-alsamixer-config-microphone-issues-what-does-pa)
- It was first ( I think ) mentioned in this post: [Microphone not working on ubuntu 18.04 with device Multichannel input-sof-hda-dsp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316407/microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-device-multichannel-input-sof-hda-ds)

Comment: To help others who are like me - you might need to jack up mic volume after this command. Go to Capture by clicking F4 while being inside alsamixer. Then increase the capture volume to max [ones with PGA]. Works perfectly after this. Also, you can add above command to 'Start Up Applications' to avoid having to run the command every time you switch on Ubuntu. Otherwise, it got reset after I shut down the computer.

Answer (score -1):

There are many possible causes of this problem.

In your **System Settings** or by directly clicking on the **Sound** icon from the bottom taskbar, go to the **Input** tab and check that the default microphone is set to your desired input device. Next, see that the input level is high enough to accept incoming voices. If this is clearly satisfied, then please proceed to next point.

Go to the software that is being used to input/record your voice. Configure in-software settings to fix the sound. From **Software Settings > Sound > Microphone > Enabled/Disabled** fix the sound issue.

If the issue is still not working out, then you have to change your software to record or input your voice.

Hope it will help you out :}

Comment: Well, that doesn't work that simple. It shows sof-hda-dsp multichannel input device, but its level is always zero (and its probably is not internal mic device). 

It is some answers addressing same issue for arch linux, but I prefer decent ubuntu solution, because experimenting porting solution from Arch can take ages (and break something on the way - and I need laptop for work)

Comment: @Lol4t0 if you want some help working out how to translate information from the Arch sources into Ubuntu, you can ask questions about that :)