# Internal Mic producing noise with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, alsa, hp, microphone

On my new hp laptop having windows os, I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04. But after this installation laptop's internal mic is not capturing my sound rather only capturing noise. This can be seen from the *settings -> sound* section as well. Input section is always showing some sound being captured which seems to be internal only and always on full.

**Note:Microphone works fine with any headset having jack or bluetooth.**

[image]

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this? I'm having the same issue on Dell xps 9500. Seems to have just recently started. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqsjt.png)

Comment: Related: [Mic not working after installing Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on my new Lenovo ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-8](https://askubuntu.com/q/1331966) ... and probably helpful: [Mic picks up all system sounds (including game sounds)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1320217)