# Internal microphone not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, microphone

my internal microphone is not recording and it looks like it is not receiving any input; see Settings -> Sound.

[image: sound settings]

Here is what `pavucontrol` shows (when I 'unlock' it I see the input audio at the minimum).

[image: pavucontrol]

When I connect my headphones everything works smoothly: I can hear sound and use the microphone.

Here is the the output of `alsamixer`:

[image: alsamixer1]

[image: alsamixer2]

[image: alsamixer3]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mic not working after installing Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on my new Lenovo ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331966/mic-not-working-after-installing-ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-on-my-new-lenovo-thinkpad-x1)

Comment: unluckily that did not help. thanks for hint @Raffa