# Internal microphone not working on Dell precision 7530

Tags: 22.04, laptop, microphone

**Problem:** Internal microphone does not work

**Question:** How do I get the microphone to work?

**Setup:**

- Model: Dell Precision 7530
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04
- Kernel verion: 5.17.0-1025-oem (recently switched from non-oem)

**I already tried:**

- Selecting Stereo duplex in Pavucontrol
- Unmuting in Pavucontrol
- Checking microphone levels in Alsamixer (Though there are only "headset" and "headphone" options and none for an integrated microphone)
- Reinstalling alsamixer and pulseaudio
- blacklisting "snd_hda_intel" in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
- Installing SOF firmware and topology binaries
- Testing external mic on headphones with a 3.5mm jack and on a usb webcam (both worked out of the box)
- Checking other answers

**(Hopefully) relevant info:**

> lspci -v

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Dell Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 149, IOMMU group 14
    Memory at b5330000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 404a000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl


01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17, IOMMU group 1
    Memory at b3080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

> lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                73728  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_rawmidi            45056  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_ctl_led            24576  0
snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl    16384  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common   102400  1 snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
soundwire_intel        40960  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
soundwire_generic_allocation    16384  1 soundwire_intel
soundwire_cadence      36864  1 soundwire_intel
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_pci            20480  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof               163840  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_ext_core       32768  3 
snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    61440  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
soundwire_bus          94208  3 
soundwire_intel,soundwire_generic_allocation,soundwire_cadence
snd_soc_core          339968  4 
soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
rfcomm                 81920  16
xt_nat                 16384  9
xt_tcpudp              20480  11
veth                   32768  0
xt_conntrack           16384  3
nft_chain_nat          16384  7
xt_MASQUERADE          20480  4
nf_nat                 49152  3 xt_nat,nft_chain_nat,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_conntrack_netlink    49152  0
nf_conntrack          172032  5 
xt_conntrack,nf_nat,xt_nat,nf_conntrack_netlink,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
xfrm_user              40960  1
xfrm_algo              16384  1 xfrm_user
xt_addrtype            16384  2
nft_compat             20480  29
nf_tables             253952  213 nft_compat,nft_chain_nat
libcrc32c              16384  3 nf_conntrack,nf_nat,nf_tables
nfnetlink              20480  4 nft_compat,nf_conntrack_netlink,nf_tables
br_netfilter           32768  0
bridge                303104  1 br_netfilter
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp
ccm                    20480  9
cmac                   16384  3
algif_hash             16384  1
algif_skcipher         16384  1
af_alg                 32768  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   28672  2
overlay               147456  2
dell_rbtn              20480  0
joydev                 32768  0
intel_tcc_cooling      16384  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
mei_pxp                20480  0
coretemp               24576  0
mei_hdcp               24576  0
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
dell_laptop            32768  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   151552  1
snd_hda_codec_generic   102400  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     73728  2
snd_hda_intel          53248  4
snd_intel_dspcfg       32768  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         155648  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core          110592  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
dell_smm_hwmon         24576  0
snd_pcm               147456  10 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
kvm_intel             425984  0
binfmt_misc            24576  1
iwlmvm                581632  0
kvm                  1032192  1 kvm_intel
```

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1331966

Answer (score 0):

After further digging around I figured it out.

**My laptop does not have an internal microphone at all.**

It may come as a surprise, but apparently not every laptop does have an internal microphone.