# No microphone on a Lenovo Thinkpad running Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04, alsa, microphone

When I navigate to "Sounds" in system settings, there are [no options for microphone input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5SPU.png).

I've tried `pavucontrol` and it also detects no options. I've tried adding:

```
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

to my `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file and rebooting, with no success.

What might be the root cause of my issue and how might I fix it?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1336123