# No sound devices on Lenovo x1 carbon after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, thinkpad, microphone, soundcard

I have upgraded my Lenovo X1 Carbon to Ubuntu 20.04. After the reboot, I cannot see any sound card nor for input nor for output.
I have tried to follow several different solutions such as:

- [Microphone not working on ubuntu 18.04 with device Multichannel input-sof-hda-dsp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316407/microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-device-multichannel-input-sof-hda-ds)
- [18.04 issues with X1 Carbon: alsamixer config + Microphone issues: What does "pacmd" do here?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336087/18-04-issues-with-x1-carbon-alsamixer-config-microphone-issues-what-does-pa)
- [Mic not working after installing Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on my new Lenovo ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331966/mic-not-working-after-installing-ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-on-my-new-lenovo-thinkpad-x1)
- [ubuntu 22.04 audio output not working (dummy audio)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406646/ubuntu-22-04-audio-output-not-working-dummy-audio)

but unfortunately I could not figure out how to make the microphone and the speakers work. I am not aware of sound management on Ubuntu so I'm starting a bit from scratch.

What information could be useful for you to help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Talk:Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Carbon_(Gen_7)#Microphone

tl;dr: basically you need to install a firmware called [sof-firmware](https://archlinux.org/packages/?name=sof-firmware) although it still doesn't solve the problem of the microphone array not being recognized.

Comment: Can you give a few more details as to how you solved the issue? Link only answers are rarely helpful to other users...